# Can I use Joomla for two seperate websites?

Tags: hosting

I use Joomla for my work website and like it but I want to move my personal website to Joomla. I initially registered my website through NameCheap.com and tried using their Website Builder but their templates can't do what I know I can do in Joomla. At this point, I'm willing to start over (don't need to transfer content) but I want to use a separate login to access them and don't intend to share a database.

So, is it possible to do this and what are the steps to transfer a URL and create separate logins on Joomla? Yes, I'm a noob...:-)

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] to get the vibe of what this community is about.  I don't quite understand the struggle that you are experiencing.  You want to clone your business site as the foundation of the new site on the same host?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set up a Joomla site on Namecheap. I have several of them there. Just install Joomla in your public_html directory. I am assuming you are not also hosting your work website on Namecheap - but if you are, you can host multiple Joomla sites on one hosting account in Namecheap (I have done this as well).  You would just need to install Joomla into a separate root directory on NameCheap (i.e. at the same level as your public_html) then point the domain name (URL) to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is probably more of a hosting question than a Joomla question

You can host multiple Joomla websites on the same hosting account with separate databases as long as your hosting plan allows this.

Normally you would set up the second domain as an "add-on" domain and files can go in a subdirectory such as /public_html/personal or along side the current root directory such as /public_html_personal

To point your personal domain name to the work hosting, you'll need to log in to the domain name control panel and update the name server settings to the ones for your work hosting. These changes will take a few hours to propagate.

Remember to keep Joomla and third party extensions up to date on both websites as if one gets compromised, then they will probably both become compromised.